# Date Field Search not working in CGridView - YII Framework

Tags: yii

I am trying to search Date field in CGridView data, I could not get the searched values in grid for the given date.

My Model Search(),

```
public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('crm_base_contact_id',$this->crm_base_contact_id);
        $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
        $criteria->compare('created',$this->created);       
        $criteria->compare('createdby',$this->createdby,true);
        $criteria->compare('description',$this->description);
        $criteria->compare('is_active',$this->is_active);
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```

My Grid View for CJuiDatePicker,

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'basecontact-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    //'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array('class'=>'CButtonColumn',),
        'name',
        'crm_base_contact_id',      
                   array(
            'name'=>'is_active',
            'filter'=>CHtml::dropDownList('Event[is_active]', '',  
                array(
                    ''=>'',
                    '1'=>'Y',
                    '0'=>'N',
                )
            ),
            'value' =>'($data->is_active==1)?"Y":"N"',
        ),
        array(  'name'=>'created',
                'header'=>'created',
                'value' => '$data->createdDate',),
        'createdby',
        'description',
    ),
)); ?>
```

createdDate() in Model  to format date like "dd/mm/yyyy",

```
function getCreatedDate()
    {

      if ($this->created === null || $this->created === ('0000-00-00 00:00:00'))
        return "";

      return Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("d/M/y", $this->created);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: did you find your answer?

Comment: after pasted also same error sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this?

```
$Date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($this->created)); // get proper Y-m-d
$startOfDay = $Date . ' 00:00:00'; // from start of the day
$endOfDay = $Date . ' 23:59:59';   // until end of the day

// the rows between these
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('created', strtorime($startOfDay) , strtotime(endOfDay) );
```

Comment: Yes used still Grid values is empty before search itself

Comment: if you want your grid to be pre populated with some data, in your criteria, implement a logic like, if there is no $_POST or $_GET, have some default data for criteria, btw your pic, don't show that your filtering. if so, your inputs lose their value after search, your have to assign them their own value, not ''.

Answer (score 1):

In the model's search function, I changed the following line:

```
  $criteria->compare('fecha',$this->fecha,true);
```

By this long but working code:

```
  if ($this->fecha) { // this way with avoid the empty search grid
    if (strlen($this->fecha) == 10) // full date entered
      $criteria->compare('fecha', date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->fecha)));
    elseif (strlen($this->fecha) > 2) { // dd-mm entered
      $this->fecha = $this->fecha . date("-Y");
      $criteria->compare('fecha', date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->fecha)));
    } else { // dd only entered
      $this->fecha = $this->fecha . date("-m-Y");
      $criteria->compare('fecha', date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->fecha)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in search()

```
   $criteria->compare('created',date("Y-m-d",strtotime($this->created),true);
```

instead of

```
   $criteria->compare('created',$this->created);
```

Comment: Yes changed the above mentioned line, still not getting, after included the line grid record not display while opening the form